# How to manage state change in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, state

```
public void manage()
    {
        double speed = getSpeedfromVehicle();

        if(speed >=0 && speed <= 10)
        {
            System.out.println("Low Speed mode");
        }
        else if(speed > 10 && speed < 60)
        {
            System.out.println("Medium Speed Mode");
        }
        else if(speed >= 60)
        {
            System.out.println("High Speed Mode");
        }

    }
```

When the vehicle starts moving my manage method is called for each and every speed change.
If the speed stays in one category (0 to 10) i need to print the output statement only once even tough the manage() is called infinite times for speed 0 to 10. This should happen for other speed ranges as well. It also should switch to other speed ranges and should print each speed range only once.

Comment: I guess you'd need to set some kind of state information, like a `boolean` flag, or the current speed, on the class instance where `public void manage()` is located.

Comment: What is the question, and where is the loop mentioned in the title?

Comment: If you read better the "loop" is at _When the vehicle starts moving my manage method is called for each and every speed change_. Not a programming loop anyway.

Comment: @kiheru and dic19: Did you read the paragraph under the code?

Comment: Well you need to know the speed from the previous state. This way, you can detect when speed transitions between states. Perhaps you can even have an `Enum Speed { LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH }`...

Comment: Your text is not in agreement with your code sample. You say 0-5 in the text block, but your if statement is from 0-10.

Comment: How to get a speed Change notification once ?? I mean when the speed is changed from one state to another i need to print "Speed Changed" once.

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a variable to check against that states the current speed mode. I would consider using an enum class with with my speed states as values. Each time the speed range changes, you update the local SpeedState enum value and validate against it in the manage() method.

Off the top of my head it would look like the following...

```
public enum SpeedState {
    LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}    


public class Drive{
    private SpeedState state;

    // Supporting code, loops, etc

    public void manage(){
        double speed = getSpeedfromVehicle();

        if((speed >=0 && speed <= 10) && state != SpeedState.LOW)
        {
           state = SpeedState.LOW;
           System.out.println("Low Speed mode");
        }
        else if((speed > 10 && speed < 60) && state != SpeedState.MEDIUM)
        {
           state = SpeedState.MEDIUM;
           System.out.println("Medium Speed Mode");
        }
        else if((speed >= 60) && state != SpeedState.HIGH)
        {
           state = SpeedState.HIGH;
           System.out.println("High Speed Mode");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Storing the state is the best way to handle this, as I mentioned as the first comment to the OP's question.

Comment: Is there a need for 3 States? I believe it would require only 2 booleans or states , if its slow set the slow true, if its fast set the fast as true, if both are false, then it should be medium speed.

Comment: There's not necessarily a need for three states in this example, but what if they need to add overdrive. :) This solution allows for extension.

Comment: Also, you can add the speed values to the enum itself so that you'll call `SpeedState.forSpeed(speed)` which will return the right state.

Comment: How to get a speed Change notification once ?? I mean when the speed is changed from one state to another i need to print "Speed Changed" once.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the [State pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state). Then have a state for high, low, and mid. This way you can encapsulate the behaviors of each state. When you transition from one state to another, you can perform your desired action on transition. This is a more elegant solution than a loop, and will be easier to maintain going forward.

Here's an example of how you can use the state pattern to manage your car's state as regards speed.

```
package test;

public class Car {

    private int speed;
    private Speedo speedo = new LowSpeed();

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void manage() {
        this.speedo = speedo.manage(speed);
    }

}

abstract class Speedo {
    private int lowRange;
    private int highRange;
    private Speedo lowState;
    private Speedo highState;

    public Speedo getLowState() {
        return lowState;
    }

    public Speedo getHighState() {
        return highState;
    }

    public int getLowRange() {
        return lowRange;
    }

    public void setLowRange(int lowRange) {
        this.lowRange = lowRange;
    }

    public int getHighRange() {
        return highRange;
    }

    public void setHighRange(int highRange) {
        this.highRange = highRange;
    }

    public abstract void onLowTransition();

    public abstract void onHighTransition();

    public Speedo manage(int speed) {
        if (speed < getLowRange()) {
            onLowTransition();
            return getLowState();
        } else if (speed > getHighRange()) {
            onHighTransition();
            return getHighState();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }
}

class LowSpeed extends Speedo {

    public Speedo manage(int speed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onHighTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class MidSpeed extends Speedo {

    public Speedo manage(int speed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onHighTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class HighSpeed extends Speedo {

    public Speedo manage(int speed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onHighTransition() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is incomplete, but it will give you a good foundation to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a `boolean isUpdated` as your instance variable and update the `boolean` in the `if condition`.

Before printing the statement just check if the boolean is true or false.

```
public class CarSpeed{

    private boolean slow;
    private boolean fast;

    public CarSpeed(){
         slow = false;
         fast = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        .....
        .....
    }

    public void manage()
    {
        double speed = getSpeedfromVehicle();

        if(speed >=0 && speed <= 10 && slow == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Low Speed mode");
            slow = true;
        }
        else if(speed > 10 && speed < 60 && slow == false && fast == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Medium Speed Mode");
        }
        else if(speed >= 60 & fast == false)
        {
            System.out.println("High Speed Mode");
            fast = true;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: If the Speed range categories increases then the flags increases....

Comment: @user1635256 Yes thats true. If there are more conditions to be satisfied the code/equation will change.

Comment: How to get a speed Change notification once ?? I mean when the speed is changed from one state to another i need to print "Speed Changed" once.

Answer (score 0):

Use a State enum variable to conditionally update the state

```
enum SpeedMode {
    LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
};

private SpeedMode speedMode;

public void manage() {
    double speed = getSpeedfromVehicle();

    if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 10 && speedMode!=SpeedMode.LOW) {
        speedMode=SpeedMode.LOW;
        System.out.println("Low Speed mode");
    } else if (speed > 10 && speed < 60 && speedMode!=SpeedMode.MEDIUM) {
        speedMode=SpeedMode.MEDIUM;
        System.out.println("Medium Speed Mode");
    } else if (speed >= 60 && speedMode!=SpeedMode.HIGH) {
        speedMode=SpeedMode.HIGH;
        System.out.println("High Speed Mode");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another simple example:

public class CarSpeed {

```
enum Speed {
    SLOW("Slow"),MEDIUM("Medium"),FAST("Fast");
    String speedString;
    Speed(String speedString) {
        this.speedString = speedString;
    }
    static Speed getCurrentSpeed(double currentSpeed) {
        if (currentSpeed <= 10)
            return SLOW;
        else if (currentSpeed >10 && currentSpeed <= 60)
            return MEDIUM;
        else
            return FAST;
    }
    String getSpeedString() {
        return speedString;
    }
}

private Speed currentSpeed = Speed.SLOW; 


public void manage() {
    Speed newSpeed = Speed.getCurrentSpeed(getSpeedfromVehicle());

    if (currentSpeed != newSpeed) {
        currentSpeed = newSpeed;
        System.out.println("It's now going " + currentSpeed.getSpeedString() + "!");
    }

}

double speed;
public double getSpeedfromVehicle() {
    return speed;
}
public void setSpeedfromVehicle(double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you go with one of these solutions:

```
if((speed >=0 && speed <= 10) && state != SpeedState.LOW)
...
else if((speed > 10 && speed < 60) && state != SpeedState.MEDIUM)
...
else if((speed >= 60) && state != SpeedState.HIGH)
...
```

Then please not that this code does too many comparisions.
For example: if current state is `LOW` and current speed is `5` then the first condition `((speed >=0 && speed <= 10) && state != SpeedState.LOW)` is going to return `false`, **BUT**, because of the `else if` it is going to check for other conditions as well, but what for? We already know that the speed must be `LOW`, there's no need to do other checks.

So here is a bit better version:

```
public enum SpeedState {
    LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH
}

public class Drive {
    private SpeedState state;

    public void manage() {
        double speed = getSpeedfromVehicle();

        SpeedState newState = null;

        if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 10)
            newState = SpeedState.LOW;
        else if (speed > 10 && speed < 60)
            newState = SpeedState.MEDIUM;
        else if (speed >= 60)
            newState = SpeedState.HIGH;

        if (newState != state) {
            state = newState;
            System.out.println("State changed to" + state);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution with predefined speed range in enum object in case if your speed has integer increment. In case of double type of speed change 11 to 10, 61 to 60 and check minimum value as a exclusive value.

```
public enum SpeedMode {
    LOW(0, 10), MEDIUM(11, 60), HIGH(61, 300);

    private final int minSpeed;
    private final int maxSpeed;

    SpeedMode(int minSpeed, int maxSpeed) {
        this.minSpeed = minSpeed;
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    public int getMinSpeed() {
        return this.minSpeed;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return this.maxSpeed;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class SpeedSelector {
    private SpeedMode speedMode;
    private boolean speedChanged;

    public SpeedSelector() {
        this.speedMode = SpeedMode.LOW;
        this.speedChanged = true;
    }

    public void change(int speed) {
        boolean validSpeed = false;

        for (SpeedMode speedMode : SpeedMode.values()) {
            if (speedMode.getMinSpeed() <= speed
                    && speed <= speedMode.getMaxSpeed()) {
                            validSpeed = true;
                if (this.speedMode != speedMode) {
                    speedChanged = true;
                    this.speedMode = speedMode;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!validSpeed)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid speed range");
    }

    public SpeedMode getSpeedMode() {
        return speedMode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (speedChanged) {
            speedChanged = false;
            return "Speed changed to " + speedMode.name();
        } else
            return "";
    }

}
```

---

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpeedSelector speedSelector = new SpeedSelector();
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
        speedSelector.change(23);
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
        speedSelector.change(25);
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
        speedSelector.change(100);
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
        speedSelector.change(150);
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
        speedSelector.change(10);
        System.out.println(speedSelector);
    }
}
```